# Extrair index para elementos repetidos em listas no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Caso eu tenha uma lista `x` que contenha vários valores, e alguns repetidos, e eu queira ter o index para cada elemento, como eu posso fazer? tentei fazer utilizando o método `.index()` porem ele só retorna o index do primeiro elemento.

```
>>> x = ['c','a','s','a']

>>> a.index('a')
1
```

Porém o que estou tentando fazer é ter o index de cada letra, mesmo tendo dois números para as letras repetidas e passar para um dicionário:

```
x_index = {"c":0,"a":(1,3),"s":2}
```

Comment: No dicionário `x_index`, os índices precisam ser armazenados em tuplas/inteiros ou podem ser armazenados em *arrays*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar sobre a lista e obter o índice dos elementos repetidos:

```
>>> lista = ['c', 'a', 's', 'a']
>>> [i for i, item in enumerate(lista) if item == 'a']
[1, 3]
>>>
```

Para guardar os valores e índices repetidos num [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict), primeiro verifique se a chave já existe, se afirmativo, você obtém os índices repetidos e atualiza a chave, caso contrário, apenas insira o valor:

```
dicionario = {}
lista = ['c', 'a', 's', 'a', 's']

for valor in lista:
    if valor in dicionario:
        dicionario[valor] = [i for i, item in enumerate(lista) if item == valor]
    else:
        dicionario[valor] = lista.index(valor)

print (dicionario)
# {'a': [1, 3], 'c': 0, 's': [2, 4]}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/Dbsc)</kbd>

A ordem do dicionário nem sempre será a mesma, se você precisar que a ordem seja preservada, use um [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dicionario = OrderedDict()
# ...

print (dicionario)
# OrderedDict([('c', 0), ('a', [1, 3]), ('s', [2, 4])])
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!